# Loop for Android values

Tags: java, android, loops

I would like to add some sort of loop for some values in my Android app.

I have this

```
        { 600, 0.5f },
        { 900, 0.3f },
        { 1200, 0.2f },
        { 1500, 0.3f },
        { 1800, 0.1f },
        { 2100, 0.4f },
        { 2400, 0.5f },
```

Where first column (600,900 etc) is the X coordinate and the Y coord should be somewhere between 0.1 & 0.9.

So how can i do to get different values for the Y coords each time i run my application?

Comment: what? are you just trying to randomly generate numbers every time?

Comment: I think i misunderstood you only need random values in "Y"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();

float[][] myArray = new float[][]{
{ 600, rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f },
{ 900, rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f  },
{ 1200, rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f },
{ 1500,rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f  }
};


for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {  
            for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j=j+2) {  
                float p1 = myArray[i][j]; 
                float p2 = myArray[i][j+1]; 
                System.out.println(p1+", " + p2);
            }  
        }
```

to reset it:

```
myArray = new float[][]{
{ 600, rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f },
{ 900, rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f  },
{ 1200, rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f },
{ 1500,rand.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f  }
};
```

Comment: Ok that works fine! It gives different values all over the place. :) 

But how do i reset it? Now when i get to the end and start over all the values are the same as they where when i started. I need to restart the whole app for the values to be different.

When the float is done and starts again i would like them to give new calculations.

Comment: That wont work for me. I need to reset it inside a 
    public void startAction(){
    //Stuff 
    };

Answer (score 0):

To generate a pseudorandom float between 0.1 and 0.9.

```
Random gen = new Random();
y = gen.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f;
```

Comment: Exactly! So what will i write where the 0.8 is now the and where will i put this code? Will it be inside of my 
    final float Y_positions[][] = new float[][] {
   
   { 600, 0.5f },
   { 900, 0.3f },
   { 1200, 0.2f },
};

Comment: @RichardStenstierna You only asked how to get a different value each time. See MobileMon's answer if you want your code written for you.

Comment: Ok my bad. I wrote before i thinked.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random r = new Random();
//range 600 > 2400
int myX = r.nextInt(2400 - 600) + 600;
//range 0.1 > 0.9
Float myY = r.nextFloat() * 0.8f + 0.1f;


Log.i("Random Value of X", String.valueOf(myX));
Log.i("Random Value of Y", String.valueOf(myY));
```

Comment: Thats really nice! :)